# Using a =Application in an If-Then statement in class asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Is there a way to use an `=Application` in an If-Then statement? I've got     `Application("rights") = "Rights"` in my global.asa. I'd like to put it within my html i.e.

```
<a <% If info="Rights" %> class="this"<%End If %> href="link.com">Rights</a>` so is there some way to do `<a <% If info="<% =Application("rights")%>" %> class="this"<%End If %> 
href="link.com">Rights</a>
```

but to actually have it working?

Comment: For what reason?

Comment: No idea what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a strange request, I'll explain why.

The `Application` level variables are stored for the life of a Web Application *(server restarted, World Wide Web Publishing Service is stopped or individual website is stopped in IIS)*.

Whereas what you seem to want is a `Session` level variable as "Rights" suggests some kind of permission value that will likely be different per user of the Web Application, which storing it at the `Application` scope level will not give you. Instead, you want to consider using `Session` objects which can be enabled in the ASP properties in IIS by setting `Enable Session State` to `True` *(see [ASP Session `<session>`](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp/session))*

Back to the question,

`Application` or `Session` scoped variables can be used like any other variable in Classic ASP.

You can;

Assign to a local variable to reuse

```
<%
Dim app_rights: app_rights = Application("rights")
Dim usr_rights: usr_rights = Session("rights")
%>

<a <% If LCase(info & "") = LCase(app_rights & "") Then %> class="this"<%End If %> 
href="link.com">Rights</a>

<a <% If LCase(info & "") = LCase(usr_rights & "") Then %> class="this"<%End If %> 
href="link.com">Rights</a>
```

Call directly

```
<a <% If LCase(info & "") = LCase(Application("rights") & "") Then %> class="this"<%End If %> href="link.com">Rights</a>

<a <% If LCase(info & "") = LCase(Session("rights") & "") Then %> class="this"<%End If %> href="link.com">Rights</a>
```

Comment: Is there no way to use a global variable directly?

Comment: @user5753132 The second example shows using them directly, what are you actual asking?